# How can I store the value of a MySqlCommand in C# to a local variable?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am using MySql in  Windows Form Application. I want to store the result of a MySqlCommand in a string and then assign the contents of that string to a label control on my Windows form so that the label text will display the result of the MySqlCommand.
I have tried the bottom code but that doesn't work.

```
 public void WhoLogIn()
    {
        _con.Open();
        MySqlCommand NewCommand = new MySqlCommand("select titleandfullname from users where username ='" + Variables.whologin + "';", _con);
        //Variables.whologin is a public const string in a class declared in another file.
        MySqlDataReader result;
        result = NewCommand.ExecuteReader();
        string _nameofwhologin;

        while (result.Read())
        {
            _nameofwhologin = result.GetString(0);
        }
        _nameofwhologin = label2.Text;

    }
```

I would like help on how to achieve this using corrections to the code or the proposal of a different method altogether.

Comment: first off fix the obvious mistake `label2.Text = _nameofwhologin;` not `_nameofwhologin = label2.Text;`

Comment: +1 bit2know. It looks to me like this should otherwise work just fine, as long as `_con` has been set up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this;

```
 public void WhoLogIn()
    {
        _con.Open();
        MySqlCommand NewCommand = new MySqlCommand("select titleandfullname from users where username ='" + Variables.whologin + "';", _con);
        //Variables.whologin is a public const string in a class declared in another file.
        MySqlDataReader result;
        result = NewCommand.ExecuteReader();
        string _nameofwhologin;

        while (result.Read())
        {
            _nameofwhologin = result.GetString(0);
        }
        label2.Text=_nameofwhologin;

    }
```